# WCF Security model implementation

Tags: c#, wcf-security

I have a Web Service, Now I want to implement security model for that, Can you suggest me some tutorials which talks about implementing security on service and also on client. 
i tried OAUTH but there is not much implementation details about Service, tough Client implementation details are present in few blogs. Please Point me to some relative stuff where i can learn about security implementation. I am using WebHttpBinding in my WCF Service and its written in C#.

Comment: There aren't enough implementation details for OAuth?? I wrote a library from scratch in about 2 days directly from the spec, which interoperates fine with all providers and clients I've tried. OK, some parts are a little fuzzy and leave things open to interpretation, but its certainly well specified enough to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN has an entire section devoted to [Security for WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735093.aspx).

Most of the details are in their [Securing Services and Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734736.aspx) section of documentation.  This discusses the details of the entire security model when using WCF, both on the server and the client.